# Write to Json File in internal memory using JSONObject android

Tags: android, json

My json file is look like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "hardik2",
        "note": "new note created",
        "date": "current date"
    },
    {
        "title": "hardik2",
        "note": "2 new note",
        "date": "2 current date"
    },
        ......I want to add same object here like previous one
]
```

i want to add more objects in the same array without loosing previous one
how to do it?

i am currently doing is:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream=openFileOutput("note.json",MODE_APPEND);

JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("title",title.getText().toString());
jsonObject.put("date","current date");
jsonObject.put("note",note.getText().toString());

jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
outputStream.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: add previous file data of `note.json` into your `JsonArray`

Comment: Keep it simple. Load your data into memory, add your new values and overwrite you file.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy way to use Gson.

[GSON](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/google/gson&ved=2ahUKEwiuj7G1ztHgAhVXinAKHTYgAmQQFjAMegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1MKZwlMw32pMKngs-HI1qu)

Solutions by Gson

First make class which have three variable title,note and date.

```
    class DataOfJson {

    private String title;
    private String note;
    private String date;


    public DataOfJson(String title, String note, String date){
    this.title=title;
    this.note=note;
    this.date=date;
    }
}
```

Add item in list

```
FileOutputStream outputStream=openFileOutput("note.json",MODE_APPEND);
String data= getStringFromFile("path/note.json");

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DataOfJson>>() {}.getType();

List<DataOfJson> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(data,listType);
yourList.add( new DataOfJson(title.getText().toStri g(),note.getText().toString(),"current date");

outputStream.write(new Gson().toJson(yourList));




 public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
        File fl = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
        String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
        //Make sure you close all streams.
        fin.close();      


    return ret;
}
```

Comment: First you get contain form note.json and set in fromJson(contain,listType)